Significance of uniqueness rules in MLTT-style systems (vs. CIC-style systems)
For context, I'm trying to compare the systems grouped under the umbrella "Martin-Löf type theory" with those under the umbrella "calculus of inductive constructions". It seems that the most important difference is the presence of an impredicative sort in CIC-style systems. Apart from that, the tradition in CIC-style systems is to have very few constructs as native (basically just $λ$ and $Π$, plus maybe let) and add the others as inductive types ($∃, Σ, ∧, ×, ∨, +, …$). In MLTT-style systems, it seems more traditional to add a number of types natively ($Σ, ×, +, 0, 1, =$, W-types), and CIC-style inductive types can be encoded with W-types. It is clear that impredicativity makes a huge amount of difference. What I'm trying to understand is how much of a difference these two styles of "inductive-like" types make.
In MLTT, most type formers are specified by five rules: formation, introduction, elimination, computation and uniqueness. It seems to me that in CIC-style systems (at least in Coq), we do not have the uniqueness rules. As a concrete example, let's take the binary product type. Here are the five rules put forward on the nLab:

Formation:

$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash A \; \mathrm{type} \quad \Gamma \vdash B \; \mathrm{type}}{\Gamma \vdash A \times B \; \mathrm{type}}$$

Introduction:

$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash a:A \quad \Gamma \vdash b:B}{\Gamma \vdash (a, b):A \times B}$$

Elimination:

$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash z:A \times B}{\Gamma \vdash \pi_1(z):A} \qquad \frac{\Gamma \vdash z:A \times B}{\Gamma \vdash \pi_2(z):B}$$

Computation:

$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash a:A \quad \Gamma \vdash b:B}{\Gamma \vdash \pi_1(a, b) \equiv a:A} \qquad \frac{\Gamma \vdash a:A \quad \Gamma \vdash b:B}{\Gamma \vdash \pi_2(a, b) \equiv b:B}$$

Uniqueness:

$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash z:A \times B}{\Gamma \vdash z \equiv (\pi_1(z), \pi_2(z)):A \times B}$$
If we compare this to, say, Coq, we have formation because we can indeed form A*B, introduction is given by the constructor pair, elimination is given by the two functions fst and snd which are defined in terms of pattern matching, and computation is verified because of how pattern matching works. What about uniqueness? It is indeed the case that pair = (fst pair, snd pair) — but this only holds propositionally (we can prove it using the eliminator of the product type, or just pattern matching). In contrast, the uniqueness rule from MLTT gives this as a definitional equality. Concretely:
Parameter (A B : Type) (pair : A*B).

Fail Check eq_refl : pair = (fst pair, snd pair).
(* cannot unify "pair" and "(fst pair, snd pair)" *)

Goal pair = (fst pair, snd pair).
Proof. destruct pair. reflexivity. Qed.

Questions:

Is this analysis correct?
Is the presence of uniqueness rules an inessential feature of MLTT that could harmlessly be added to CIC, or is there some fundamental reason why it would not work in CIC?
Do these uniqueness rules add any logical power? Edit: To make this part of the question more precise, is adding uniqueness for $×$ conservative over arithmetic? (Intuitively it should be, however this does not seem easy to prove.)
What about decidability? This kind of rule means that definitional equality, unlike traditional CIC, cannot be decided by just normalizing. In Coq, there is a form of η-conversion (uniqueness for dependent product types) where the type checker will automatically η-expand (but not η-reduce!) subterms when needed to unify two terms. I'm guessing that deciding definitional equality with these rules would work very similarly. Is that understanding correct?


I believe your analysis is not exactly right: the presence or absence of uniqueness rules is not really a feature of MLTT vs CIC, but rather of the types one considers. Note that even in MLTT $+$, $0$, $W$ or $=$ do not have a uniqueness rule. Only for $\times$/$\Sigma$ is there a choice involved of having uniqueness or not: if you encode them as inductive types, you do not get uniqueness. But in this particular case uniqueness is actually fine, and you can get it in Coq by encoding $\times$/$\Sigma$ using (primitive) records rather than inductive types.
The reason why neither MLTT nor CIC adds uniqueness rules for the type formers above is not a coincidence: these rules are at least difficult to formulate and would add a very significant overhead to conversion, when they do not make the type theory straight undecidable. At least in the case of $=$, they also make new things provable (although I don't know the situation for other extensionality rules).
For $=$, uniqueness is equality reflection (see eg the nlab page), which says
$$
\frac{\Gamma \vdash e : a =_A a'}{\Gamma \vdash a \equiv a' : A}
$$
Extensional type theory has wildly undecidable type-checking, and is not a conservative extension of intentional type theory, as you can prove function extensionality and uniqueness of identity proofs.
For $0$, uniqueness says that in an inconsistent context conversion degenerates (see McBride's Grins from my Ripley Cupboard):
$$
 \frac{\Gamma \vdash e : 0 \quad \Gamma \vdash a : A \quad \Gamma \vdash a' : A}{\Gamma \vdash a \equiv a' : A}
$$
Again, this has nasty consequences: in an inconsistent context (one in which $0$ is derivable), any conversion is true, and so any term is typable. This means typability reduces to deciding whether the context is consistent, an undecidable problem.
For the case of $\mathbb{N}$ (a simplification of $W$), extensionality would say/entail something along the lines of
$$
\frac{\Gamma, x : \mathbb{N} \vdash a : A \quad \Gamma, x : \mathbb{N} \vdash a' : A \quad \Gamma, \vdash a[0] \equiv a'[0] : A \quad \dots \quad \Gamma, \vdash a[\underline{n}] \equiv a'[\underline{n}] : A}{\Gamma, x : \mathbb{N} \vdash a \equiv a' : A}
$$
(where $\underline{n}$ denotes a numeral, ie the term $S^{n} 0$ for a meta-level natural $n$). It is widely believed this also breaks undecidability of type-checking, although I don't know any proper reference for this.
Finally, the one left is $+$. Due to its finitary behaviour, it seems more promising to get some sort of decidability. Moreover, in the context of simply-typed λ-calculus, conversion with η for sums (and for $0$) is decidable, see Scherer 2017. However, with dependent types, already in the simpler case of booleans (ie $1 + 1$), even the question of how to phrase the rule is tricky, in order to avoid breaking typing, let alone show a form of decidability (on this, see the recent work of Kenji Maillard). But in any case you'll encounter some exponential blowup as you do more and more case splitting on everything that looks like a sum, which in practice seems nasty.

You could also argue that the $\eta$ rule for identity is definitional UIP, which is somewhat less crazy than full-blown extensionality.

"This is what the Coq software implements ... Specifying these hence makes the calculus of constructions be an intensional dependent type theory"  "".  Coq proves Leibniz equality: I still do not understand why the underlying type theory (the core language?) is dubbed intensional.

Thanks for the detailed answer. One question remains: Is it known whether adding uniqueness for $×$ and $Σ$ is conservative, say, over arithmetic? (I would intuitively think it is, but that doesn't seem trivial to prove.)

@JulioDiEgidio I think the terms "intensional" and "extensional" are not so well-defined and are used to mean different things in different contexts, see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/intensional+type+theory

@JeanAbouSamra  From the article you link: << The idea is that the identity type is always an “extensional” notion of equality (although it can be more or less extensional, depending on whether further extensionality principles like function extensionality and univalence hold). >>  The degree of extensionality may differ, but simply calling Coq intensional seems to me untenable.  (Of course, I might be wrong and/or missing something.)

@JulioDiEgidio The fact that Coq's propositional equality is provably internally equivalent to Leibniz equality doesn't make this equality extensional if you take "extensional" in a more external sense because some things you externally know will satisfy the same provable properties will not be provably equal for this equality: for example, two functions with equal outputs, or two equivalent propositions. In this sense, Coq is intensional because it proves neither functional extensionality nor propositional extensionality.

Alternatively, if you take "extensional" to refer to the definitional (aka jugmental) equality, the absence of equality reflection (if $a$ and $b$ are propositionally equal then they are definitionally equal) is a sense in which Coq is "intensional". At least, that's the meaning of "extensional" in "extensional Martin-Löf type theory". But that makes the TT automatically undecidable, so I don't think anybody really looks at that today.

And lastly, "extensional equality" can refer to the equality type being a mere proposition, aka UIP, which is not provable in Coq either.

@JeanAbouSamra Hm, I'd still call it minimally-extensional rather than intensional. :) Strictly speaking, I find the latter improper and, certainly for me, quite confusing. Never mind, thanks very much for fleshing it out.

Re: conservativity of η for Σ/×, that's a good question, and I am not aware of any result in that area…

Re: about η for the identity type, definitional uip goes some way into making identity unique, but I believe extensionality is what one gets if one insists on having the identity type to have a universal property (rather than a weakly universal one) in a model. In that sense it is the "right" notion of extensionality, although you can surely try to get weaker ones. (On this, also see the nlab page).
